# Android studio unable to find data binding classes in a package

Tags: android, android-databinding

I am using Data Binding in my project. Whenever I build the project, it gives an error

```
"error: package com.example.day.*.databinding does not exist"
```

Although classes are generated and imported. It was running till now and suddenly gives an error.

Tried every solution:

> - Build > Clean > Rebuild Project
> - Invalidate Caches and Restart
> - Make Project
> - Resync gradle file

Comment: Hi Priyanka. Unfortunately the data binding run time help is a bit under developed. The best thing you can do is do a terminal build with stack trace to get the true error. Basically when any tiny thing is off in your xml, or a custom adapter is not perfectly written, like maybe set a variable with an object that is not nullable, but your adapter takes an object that is nullable etc... So just run bash gradlew assembleRelease --debug. Then scroll up to find the line number of xml that it hates, and that should point you to the right direction. Update your post with the detailed error from that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is your layout and binding class name? 
if your layout name is activity_main.xmli your binding class name must to be ActivityMainBinding.java

Also check your layout. Do have layout file data tag. example:

```
<data class="MainActivityBinding">
    <variable
        name="user"
        type="com.example.administrator.my_mvvm.User" />
</data>
```

after check all this clean project - rebuild project

Comment: This error is throwing for every class. It was working perfectly few hours ago. And yes, layouts have data tag. Binding class name is also correct.

Comment: what is change in few hours?

Comment: Nothing. Just created new layout and class file for same without layout tag.

Comment: did you try rebuild delete new layout and and class file?

Comment: Yes, tried now by deleting new layout and class file and it is working now. But why it was causing issue?

Comment: Still facing same issue. I created new Adapter class with non data binding layout file and it gives same error. I deleted adapter class and it is working fine.